# angular.js:13550 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'popCntrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I am teaching myself AngularJS and I am trying to get a simple popup to open. But I keep getting the error in the title above. I have looked at other peoples examples of this error and none have seem to match my use case.

Things I have tried:
-checked capitalization

Other than that I am not 100% sure where I am going wrong.

Below is the Plunker where I am testing my code.

https://embed.plnkr.co/2blgWkwg0Se2SlLmuBrA/

Any help at all would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your 'popUp' module correctly here:

```
angular.module('popUp',['ui.bootstrap']);
```

But you nevere include the 'popUp' module in your main application module ('myApp'). Simply add it to the list of dependencies:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router', 'popUp']);
```

Here is an [updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/680XNT?p=preview) with a working modal.

Comment: Holy crap it was that simple all along! Thank you for the help and I have one more question for you. If I add another module do I just add them to the array?

Comment: It depends. You don't always have to add them to your main module, but it doesn't hurt to add them.